# XML DOM structure in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

How can I achieve the below XML DOM structure in PHP?

[image: XML structure]

Could you please help me out with this? Any suggestions, help is much appreciated.

**Edit** 
I have attached the attempted code. It doesn't work & I don't know how I can break that like I've attached above.

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all? Can you show some code and where you are having problems?

Comment: You could use an XML library or an array of arrays of arrays.

Comment: @Mike Brant: See the edited question.

Comment: Read up on namespacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works:

```
$doc->createElement("name:lname");
```

The element's name is actually `lname` and `name` is the handle of the namespace, which you must have defined somewhere. Then you need to use [createElementNS()](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.createelementns.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

To create **correct** XML file you must declare elements as [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php):

```
$employees   = array();
$employees[] = array('name' => 'Albert', 'age' => 34, 'salary' => 10000, 'lname' => 'Vidula');

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$domEmployees = $dom->createElement('employees');

foreach($employees as $employee)
{
    $domEmployee = $dom->createElement('employee');

    $domEmployee->appendChild($dom->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'name:fname', $employee['name']));
    $domEmployee->appendChild($dom->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'name:lname', $employee['lname']));
    $domEmployee->appendChild($dom->createElement('age', $employee['age']));
    $domEmployee->appendChild($dom->createElement('salary', $employee['salary']));

    $domEmployees->appendChild($domEmployee);
}


$dom->appendChild($domEmployees);

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<employees xmlns:name="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <employee xmlns:name="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <name:fname xmlns:name="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Albert</name:fname>
       <name:lname xmlns:name="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Vidula</name:lname>               
       <age>34</age>
       <salary>10000</salary>
    </employee>
</employees>
```